# Why is READ_CONTACTS permission not being read in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I've been reading on how to access the address book/contacts. I'm on a PC and have an android emulator up and running logged into my gmail. I run the code below. Up pops my address book contacts, so that is good. Unfortunately, when I select a contact, the next line isn't hit. Below the source is some output that I see in the Output window. I see some nulls in the output, but I don't know what to make of it.

the behavior i get is that after I select a contact, that window closes, and the previous screen is displayed. When I trap the exception, I get the message that the app doesn't have the READ_CONTACTS permission, yet, I am obviously setting it. I've followed the instructions here on setting things up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/contacts?tabs=android

It seems as if the permission isn't being read in the manifest or out of the assemblyinfo.cs file. Am I missing something? Does it wound like I've done something wrong?

TIA,
Wally

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
</manifest>
```

Source:

```
        var contact = await Contacts.Default.PickContactAsync();  // <-- break point is hit here
try{
if (contact == null) // <-- Breakpoint isn't hit
return;

        string id = contact.Id;
        string namePrefix = contact.NamePrefix;
        string givenName = contact.GivenName;
        string middleName = contact.MiddleName;
        string familyName = contact.FamilyName;
        string nameSuffix = contact.NameSuffix;
        string displayName = contact.DisplayName;
        List<ContactPhone> phones = contact.Phones; // List of phone numbers
        List<ContactEmail> emails = contact.Emails; // List of email addresses
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Most likely permission denied
    }
```

Comment: FYI, this is also happening with my Pixel 6.

Comment: I see that doc doesn't mention asking user for permission at runtime. See [Permissions > Checking Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=android#checking-permissions). If you get this working, please add Your Answer below, with the complete code snippet required for this permission. This will help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @toolmakersteve.  I added this code and called it.  It still need refinement, but it's a start.

```
public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestContactsReadPermission()
{
    PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        return status;

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
    {
        // Prompt the user to turn on in settings
        // On iOS once a permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
        return status;
    }

    if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.ContactsRead>())
    {
        // Prompt the user with additional information as to why the permission is needed
    }

    status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Could you please mark your reply as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I would accept that I can't accept my own as an answer for several more hours and I'll forget by then.  :-/